# Nerdtree ^G before folder and file names OSX terminal vim

Tags: macos, vim, nerdtree

There "^G" before names. It happens only when using vim in terminal. It is normal in MacVim.

[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqUAm.png)

I tried 
export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
export LANG="$LC_ALL"
but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to change arrow setting?

Comment: Same happen in there

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put `let g:NERDTreeNodeDelimiter = "\u00a0"` in your .vimrc

Answer (score 2):

See the associated [GitHub issue](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/928): the issue is that Mac's default vim doesn't have the `conceal` feature, and NERDTree doesn't do well in this case.

To fix it you can install Homebrew's vim, that is compiled with this feature, with `brew install vim`